# angular js , spring MVC angular JS code is not working in spring

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

snippet of my spring MVC is

```
      @RequestMapping(value = "/list2", method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=*/*",produces = "application/json")  
     public ResponseEntity<List<Employe>> listAllUsers() {     
     List<Employe> users = dataService.getList();

   if(users.isEmpty()){
     return new ResponseEntity<List<Employe>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
 }
       return new ResponseEntity<List<Employe>>(users, HttpStatus.OK);
  }
```

my angular js controller is  like below

```
 'use strict';
```

var app = angular.module('app',[]);

```
  app.controller('EmpController', function($scope, httpq) {

  httpq.get('http://localhost:8080/SpringHibernate/list2')
  .then(function(data) {
    $scope.users = data;
  })
  .catch(function(data, status) {
    console.error('Gists error', response.status, response.data);
  })
  .finally(function() {
    console.log("finally finished gists");
  });
});
```

my index.jsp is

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"           "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
   <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
 <html>
  <head ng-app="app" >
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859- 1">
    <title>SpringHibernate</title>
    </head>
     <body >
    <h1>Welcome to Spring Hibernate Project!!!</h1>
    <a href="/SpringHibernate/form">Please Click this Link To Proceed</a>
      <a href="/SpringHibernate/list3">Please Click this Link To Proceed</a>

     <div ng-controller="EmpController">
  <!--Body content-->
   <input ng-model="query"> Type to Search</input>
    <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="user in users | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp">
      <p>{{user.firstName}}
      <p>{{user.lastName}}
      <p>{{user.email}}
      <p>{{user.phone}}
    </li>
    </ul>

 </div>

   <script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/angular.min.js" />"        type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/app.js" />"  type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

after launching the code i am neither getting any log in my browser it looks like angular is not executing at all. please let me know what other details would be required. I have used the same URL in Postman it successfully generates the JSON response.

Comment: do you get any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put the `ng-app` attribute on the `<head>` element. So, only the head is handled by angular. The rest is purely static html, that angular doesn't care about.

Put in on `<html>` or on `<body>`.

Note that the error would be much easier to spot, by yourself, if your html code was correctly indented.

Comment: Thanks JB i was doing something foolish ;)